# Make "find in path" appear for PHPStorm

Tags: search, phpstorm

I linked a external folder to my PHPStorm project. In PHPStorm 6 I could right click the folder and do a file search.
In PHPStorm this feature is gone. Can I get it again?

Comment: Still works like that here in PhpStorm **v7.1 EAP** build.

Comment: When I click on a subfolder of that folder it works. But not with the folder at the top.

Comment: ?? You mean -- right click on a file instead of folder? If not -- please show a screenshot and clearly show where you do right click.

Comment: here is a screenshot of the differences http://oi44.tinypic.com/es41vo.jpg

Comment: I do not know what is so special about your project setup .. but the same seems to work OK for me: I have added the external folder via "Settings | Directories" and I do see the same context menu when right click on normal folder or content root. Yes, when right clicking on a file that menu item is not there (as per multiple requests from users), but it is should be there for normal folder. **Q:** would keyboard shortcut still work (with correct fields/values set) when you select that "problematic" folder in Project View?

Comment: It works with the keyboard shortcut

Comment: @LazyOne The top level "X in path" options are missing for me as well for the right-click menu, but i always assumed it was due to my weird setup (empty project with several external content roots). The keyboard shortcuts work, so i always made due with that.

Comment: @Tibos No clue at all, sorry. The only idea I have right now -- if you ever modified context menu for Project View .. try resetting it to defaults at `Settings | Menus and Toolbars` -- **maybe** it will help (but not sure at all)